# Unexpected output from elixir Enum.filter

Tags: elixir

I am learning Elixir and one of the examples I got from the PragProg book "Programming Elixir" is this:

```
iex(25)> (1..10) |> Enum.map(&(&1*&1)) |> Enum.filter(&(&1 < 20))
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

After typing the code, I tried to play with it a bit and I wrote:

```
iex(26)> (1..10) |> Enum.map(&(&1*&1)) |> Enum.filter(&(&1 > 20))   
[25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

Great, this was the expected outcome. Now when I write it like this:

```
iex(27)> (1..10) |> Enum.map(&(&1*&1)) |> Enum.filter(&(&1 > 40))   
'1@Qd'
```

Why do I get this weird `'1@Qd'` string?

Comment: Hmmm, apparently Elixir/Erlang has something defined as `[49, 64, 81, 100]`: `iex(42)> [49, 64, 81, 100] #=> '1@Qd'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It not bug in elixir, because method `[]` should return new [list](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/87be134a5b91773643ea292b521c9a8ec8167894/lib/elixir/lib/kernel/special_forms.ex#L42) as in erlang.

But for symbols with unicode number betwee 32 and 255 it return their representation in Unicode (default setting).

```
iex(25)> [31]
[31]
iex(26)> [32]
' '
iex(27)> [255]
'ÿ'
iex(28)> [256]
[256]
```

But when you start erlang with `+pc unicode` it decode more [symbols](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html):

```
 erl +pc unicode
 Erlang R16B (erts-5.10.1) [source] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

 Eshell V5.10.1  (abort with ^G)  
 1> [1024].
 "Ѐ"
 2> [1070,1085,1080,1082,1086,1076].
 "Юникод"
```

Comment: Duh, I should have thought of that :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"2.3 Strings (binaries) and char lists (lists)" in the getting started guide may be related on this topic.

http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/2.html

Comment: If you just want to check the values on display, the followings would be one option.

    `iex(39)> (1..10) |> Enum.map(&(&1*&1)) |> Enum.filter(&(&1 > 40)) |> Enum.join(",") 
    -> "49,64,81,100"`

    `iex(40)> (1..10) |> Enum.map(&(&1*&1)) |> Enum.filter(&(&1 > 40)) |> list_to_tuple   
    -> {49, 64, 81, 100}`